# mon sudo ne fonctionne plus aidé moi a résoudre ce problème

Tags: sudo

bonjour famille s'il vous plait aidé moi a résoudre ce problème.
quelle commande utiliser pour activer mon sudo?

sudo: /usr/bin/sudo doit être la propriété du uid 0 et avoir le bit setuid mis

**Google translate**: hello family please help me solve this problem. which command should I use to activate my sudo?

sudo: / usr / bin / sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Comment: Which command are you using with `sudo`? Can you [edit] your question to include your goal? This will make it easier to get an answer 

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that you have done a `sudo chown -R` or `sudo chmod -R` that has affected `/usr/bin/sudo`, and broken it. You have probably broken other parts of your system that you haven't noticed yet. For you level of experience, the easiest option is to reinstall Linux.